# GetAuthorizationGroups throws Index was outside the bounds of the array SOMETIMES

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory, active-directory-group

Below is the code used.  "Line 44" is the problem area:

```
var groups = p.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

It gives me an `Index was outside the bounds of the array` error after about a day of functioning normally.  This last bit seems to be the real booger of the situation.  I have found plenty of resolved issues for other `GetAuthorizationGroups` throwing out of bounds errors, but I can't find any solutions regarding a system that MOSTLY works.

Any and all help would be GREATLY appreciated.  And I'll do my best to rectify any issues with this posting.

Edit: Currently the only way to clear the error is to reboot the webserver.  Simply restarting IIS does not resolve the issue.

```
public override String[] GetRolesForUser(String username)
{
    //Check to see if role are already cached in Session variable
    if ((string[])System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Roles"] == null)
    {
        //Create an ArrayList to store our resultant list of groups.
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        //PrincipalContext encapsulates the server or domain against which all operations are performed.
        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "blargh.com"))
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a referance to the user account we are querying against.
                UserPrincipal p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
                //Get the user's security groups.  This is necessary to
                //return nested groups, but will NOT return distribution groups.
                var groups = p.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
                {
                    results.Add(group.SamAccountName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ProviderException("Unable to query Active Directory.", ex);
            }
        }
        // Store roles in Session for caching
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Roles"] = results.ToArray(typeof(String)) as String[];
    }
    return (string[])System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Roles"];
}
```

Comment: Is the exception for sure on the call to `GetAuthorizationGroups`, or could it be the `foreach` loop? I had a system that worked with most USERS but a few users would cause an issue when the `foreach` loop called `MoveNext` on the enumerator ... I can post my solution if you think it would help, but it doesn't apply if `GetAuthorizationGroups` itself is really throwing an exception as you stated

Comment: Have you tried looking up user by sid instead of account name? Having to reboot the entire webserver sounds to me like one of the operating system level caches for sid and username resolution could be contributing to the problem? We have had problems of that nature ... sorry I know I'm just guessing, but can feel your pain since we've had similar problems that required server reboots to fix

Comment: I'll try to change how it looks it up and see what happens.  This is inherited code, of course, so my familiarization with it extends only as far as the issues that have arisen.  As it is I already had to fix a C++ problem in another program having only a first year students knowledge of C++.

Comment: Also, in answer to your inquiry, the "Source Error" portion of the error message indicates line 44 and has that line highlighted. You would know better than me the likelihood of it actually being a line AFTER the specified line.